# Creating a choice columns with the same choices

Tags: infopath, custom-form, choice-field

I'm trying to create a multiple choice columns in a SharePoint list that have the some choices but are selected for different reasons.  The list I am creating is related to tracking certain conditions.  I would like to represent it on a form as I have outlined below:

[image]

I can create a column called "sent" with the choices of types of communications listed and likewise  create a column called "returned"  with the same choices of communications, but it would be repetitive in that the choices would be list twice.

Can someone help me figure out how to build what I've described perhaps by hiding the values of the second choice column (i.e. returned column) or info path or some other manner?

Thanks.

Ameer

Answer (score 0):

Have all the choices in one column with multiple selections. All in one spot and easy to figure out.

Alternatively, you could have several choice columns and depending on the value would diplay something different in a separate calculated column using a formula.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure that I made myself clear.

In my example, I want to be able to mark that the welcome letter was sent and returned. If I create a column called "sent" with an option of "welcome letter", I find that I need to also create a column called "returned" with the option of "welcome letter." The options listed would allow for multiple options to be selected such as "notification letter", "warning letter", etc.

Instead I would like to eliminate the need to have the same choices listed twice in order to track if the option selected was sent, returned or both. I would like to have the options for the column "returned" hidden so that the checkboxes are only visible. Think about having an excel sheet where Column A = options, Column B = sent and Column C = returned. There is no need to repeat Column A.

Does that make sense?